# Testing purchase process in RSpec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec, integration-testing

I'm trying to test the order process in a request spec by filling out the purchase form:

```
describe "CC order" do
  before do
    visit order_path "product"
    fill_in "full_name", with: "test name"
    fill_in "email", with: "test@email.com"
    fill_in "card_number", with: "4242424242424242"
    fill_in "card_cvc", with: "123"
    # etc...

    click_on "complete-button"
  end

  it "should display confirmation message" do
    page.should have_content "Thanks for your order!"
  end
end
```

A new User and Order should be saved after the purchase form is submitted and does so correctly in development. However, my test fails because instead of processing the order it tells me that the database is locked:

[image: Database locked]

I do have transactional fixtures turned on and some of my other tests use them. Is there another way I should be testing my order process?

EDIT: It seems like it open happens when I use `page` in the it block. If I just make the test block empty, everything works fine.

Comment: The one time this happened to me it turned out I was running the same test suite in another terminal session. Oops.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it - `ps | grep ruby` doesn't show anything else either. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running out of ideas so I switched from sqlite to postgresql in development + test. That fixed the problem.